# como puedo guardar datos de un array de objetos en laravel con curl

Tags: laravel

estoy llamando unos datos de una api, los traigo correctamente y los puedo mostrar, pero adicionalmente necesito guardarlos en la bd, lo quiero hacer con un foreach pero me arroja un error, no se como armar el foreach para que me funcione

Este es mi codigo del controlador

```
 public function getdata(){
    $header = array();
    $header [] = 'Authorization: Bearer 
    eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJQb3N0dWxhY2l';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,  'https://url.com/api/aves'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $result = curl_exec($curl); /** Ejecutamos petición*/
    $json = json_decode($result);
    foreach($json as $ans) {   //22
        $anss = Post::create([
            'id' => $ans['id'],
            'nombre' => $ans['nombre'],
            'nombreingles'=>$ans['nombreIngles'],
            'nombrelatin'=> $ans['nombreLatin'],
            'url'=> $ans['url'],
            'fechaRegistro' =>$ans['fechaRegistro']
        ]);
    }
    return $json;

  }
```

el postman me responde

```
ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file 
C:\xampp\htdocs\AjaxCrud\app\Http\Controllers\ajaxcrud\AveController.php on line 22
```

Cuando retorno solamente los datos me los muestra de la siguiente forma

```
   [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Aguilucho Chico",
    "nombreIngles": "White-throated Hawk",
    "nombreLatin": "Buteo albigula",
    "url": 
    "https://aves.ninjas.cl/api/site/assets/files/3099/1as_rivas_web.jpg",
    "fechaRegistro": "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Pato Juarjual",
    "nombreIngles": "Crested Duck",
    "nombreLatin": "Lophonetta specularioides",
    "url": "https://aves.ninjas.cl/api/site/assets/files/3102/1_valencia_web.jpg",
    "fechaRegistro": "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
   }]
```

Comment: Lo que te está devolviendo es un array con objetos, y lo estás intentando tratar como si fuera un array de arrays.  Cambia esto: `$json = json_decode($result);` por esto `$json = json_decode($result, true);` para que luego, cuando consigas entrar en el **foreach**, los datos sean correctamente tratados.  Aún así, ese no es tu error actual, el cual diria que está relacionado en que no te devuelve nada. Revisa la url y el token.  Y agrega también la opción CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER en **true**.

Comment: y quizás debas poner el `Authorization: Bearer` en una linea y no en dos

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de **cambiar el objeto** puedes **cambiar el código**. Mientras menos manosees los datos, mejor, las conversiones son más costosas y siempre suponen un riesgo: algo puede fallar en la conversión y fastidiarlo todo.

Entonces, si es un objeto, simplemente para leer **usa la notación de objeto** que es `$objeto->propiedad` en vez de usar la de array que es `$array['key']`, que es lo que haces ahora y por eso da error.

Es decir, sería cuestión de escribir el código así:

```
$json = json_decode($result, false);
foreach($json as $ans) {   //22
    $anss = Post::create([
        'id' => $ans->id,
        'nombre' => $ans->nombre,
        'nombreingles'=>$ans->nombreIngles,
        'nombrelatin'=> $ans->nombreLatin,
        'url'=> $ans->url,
        'fechaRegistro' =>$ans->fechaRegistro
    ]);
}
```

Es más, podrías tener alguna biblioteca de mapeo (supongo que existirá alguna en Laravel o en PHP puro) que te permita mapear el objeto directamente a una lista de objetos del tipo `Post` sin necesidad del  `foreach` ni de asignar a mano cada propiedad. Es cierto que algunas columnas se llaman distinto, por ejemplo, `nombreingles` en el POJO tiene una `I` mayúscula, pero eso lo puedes normalizar, igualándolo, sea en el POJO, sea en la tabla y si no es posible por algún motivo, puedes usar un alias en la consulta que trae los datos.

Comment: me arroja el mismo error, use echo gettype($json); antes de la conversion y me arroja string, cuando aplico json_decode($json) me arroja null, todo esto antes del foreach

Comment: @Jakethedog muestra el resultado de un `var_dump($json);`, puede que estés recibiendo un json no válido.